# Frequent and severe spike during Reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I apply reinforcement learning to solve a specific problem(time-series prediction). Here is the training curve. The red one indicates the cumulative reward each episode, the blue one indicates the prediction error.[image: Training Curve]. 
The network is trained in tensorflow, optimized by Adam. And the specific RL method is proximal policy optimization. I wonder how to avoid such terrible spike.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be too spiky. I would say that the amount of noise here is pretty moderate, so I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: I am sorry but do you mean that such amount of noise is normal for reinforcement learning? I can not find that the neural network had studied anything...

Comment: This amount of noise in a training curve wouldn't look out of place anywhere, even in a supervised learning setup. The reward has massively improved from -2500 to -1000, so I don't see any problems from the graph.

Comment: But if the curve is up and down with such high frequency, how can i determine whether the training is finished?

Comment: You can plot a moving average to see the trends with less noise.

Comment: Thank you, I plot a moving average and the curve is added above. Do you think there is anyway to improve this curve, such as accelerating or increasing the reward largely

Comment: @mac wang, does the machine solve the problem well after the training?

Comment: Not really well, it performs depends on the initial state